# No devices were found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

i installed nvidia-driver-455 and didn't be detected by setting of laptop as in
[image]

[image]
and when i used

```
nvidia-smi
No devices were found
```

i tried to remove driver and reinstall it but this problem exists

**Edit**

i got

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-435 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-455 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

vendor   : Intel Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

**Edit 2**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e9b
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3ffd
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f11 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3ffd
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: i'm already disabled it

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: i did it ........

Comment: The driver is installed and working. Can you run Nvidia X Server Settings utility?

Comment: i tried to open it but it couldn't be load .. and tried to use the command and got ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

Comment: So what is the Nvidia adapter? It seems to be very new.

Comment: Try to install the 450 driver. The `455` is a beta.

Comment: Excuse me how can I know the nvidia adapter ? Did you mean the version ?

Comment: Well, you should know the specs. It seems it is 2060.

Comment: Yes it is rtx 2060

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu release?

Comment: Version 18.4.5..

Comment: Try 20.04......

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you need to find out which versions of the NVIDIA drivers are supported for your graphics card.

To see which card/chip you are using, use

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and see the line under "model".

Now you can either browse the nvidia site and look which version is available for your card, or find other sources.

Then, if it is valid, you can choose to install the driver from the nvidia site or from the ubuntu repo (which usually is better set up to work with your ubuntu).

If you haven't had NVIDIA drivers installed on that linux installation, you might need to blacklist the open source "nouveau" drivers:

```
sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
sudo bash -c "echo options nouveau modeset=0 >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"
```

After that, or every installation of graphics drivers, please reboot.

I hope that helped,

-- Streunekater

Comment: It is a very bad advice to manually blacklist `nouveau`.

Comment: Why? I got this advice from here and from linuxconfig.org ... and it worked :) Please, give me some pointers about why this is bad advice.

Comment: There is a lot of reasons. 1) they are blacklisted automatically when you install drivers from a deb package; 2) If drivers don't install or won't build, the system won't boot, etc. It is a useless and potentionally harmful action. Also there is no need to blaclist and also `modeset=0` . So almost all the answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Pilot6! I didn't know that. But still... these instructions from other threads here and elsewhere made my system work with the nvidia drivers. And not doing that didn't help... So maybe, despite the potential problems, it helps some corner cases like mine. But of course I accept your downvote :)

Comment: Many wrong advises work in some cases. ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 Are you suggesting to remove `sudo bash -c "echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf"` from the answer, and if so, please update the answer appropriately.